# What does it mean to say data points in a complementary cumulative distribution plot are correlated?

Tags: statistics, correlation

While studying, I came across the following quote:

"A more serious disadvantage is that successive points on a cumulative distribution plot are correlated — the cumulative distribution function in general only changes a little from one point to the next, so adjacent values are not at all independent."

What does it mean to say that data points on a plot are correlated?

Comment: Where did you come across this quote? It would be useful to have the context to know what they are getting at.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen [Here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YdZjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA324&lpg=PA324&dq=%22successive+points+on+a+cumulative+distribution+plot+are+correlated%22&source=bl&ots=V_O_3Om4uw&sig=ACfU3U10D8yjm0DX9rxVwDlk1nlRnuT2YA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWnqTinsvqAhVVoVwKHeVlDmoQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22successive%20points%20on%20a%20cumulative%20distribution%20plot%20are%20correlated%22&f=false) apparently.  It suggests this is a reason for not fitting a power-law distribution to the straight line slope of the data's ecdf with log-log scales

Comment: @Henry How is that a disadvantage? If the curve is decreasing and more-or-less smooth then it's always a power law (at least locally!) :-)

Comment: You should include the source of the quote in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newman is not being precise here, but the way I understand it is that the error on the empirical cCDF (relative to the true cCDF value) will be correlated for nearby points. Whereas for a histogram, the error of the empirical frequency of nearby bins are independent, except for some global effects. (The error in the complementary cumulative is related to the sum of the errors above that point in the histogram, so you can see why it is correlated.)

As he indicates, this makes least squares regression a suboptimal method for extracting the power law, though there are deeper problems than this.